# Mymemory translate API - CURL not working

Tags: php, curl

I'm right now using the Mymemory translation API with API. I keep on getting a lot of errors it doesn't work. I do get a HTTP failed error with file_get_contents.

I use this code:

```
$text = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'text');
$from = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'from');
$to = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'to');

$url = 'http://mymemory.translated.net/api/get?q=' . $text . '&langpair=' . $from . '|' . $to . '&de=SOMEEMAIL';
$curl = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

$output = curl_exec ($curl);
```

If I `var_dump` the `$curl` variable, I get this: `resource(2) of type (curl)`.

If I `var_dump` the `$output` variable, I get this:

```
string(90) "<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>
"
```

If I `var_dump` the `curl_error` function, I get this: `string(0) ""`

If I `var_dump` the `curl_errno` function, I get this: `int(0)`

I got my errors turned on and it doesn't give me any errors with error_reporting either. I don't know what I'm doing. I'm testing by the way through my xampp server localhost first.

I tried using `https://` except of `http://` but didn't change anything. If I use the url directly as `$.get`, it does work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you `urlencode`d all parameters?

Comment: Oh I didnt... it's working now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to @Passerby:

Had to use `urlencode` over the params:

```
$text = urlencode(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'text'));
$from = urlencode(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'from'));
$to = urlencode(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'to'));
```